# Export sessions data from files to REDIS

Tags: session, export, redis, file

We are moving from single server to multiple server setup for our store. The problem is that we are using file cache type and we want to preserve those sessions (long expiration, per management request when we move to Redis server (by AWS).

Is there a way to export those sessions information from files to Redis?

Thank you